# Not getting the nuserdefault value on another view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4, nsuserdefaults

In my app,

I have one array filterimage in that array some images is there.
I want that array data on another view.

I try to set nsuserdefault for filterimage with this code.

```
  NSUserDefaults *userPrefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
  userPrefs setObject:filterimage forKey:@"FILTERIMAGE"];
```

with this code i try to get filterimage array data on another page.

```
FBImage = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"FILTERIMAGE"];
```

FBImage is Array.

but get null in FBImage.

when i print data where i set user default it give like this.

```
-[NSUserDefaults setObject:forKey:]: Attempt to insert non-property value '(
    "<null>",
    "<null>",
    "http://external.ak.fbcdn.net/safe_image.php?d=AQD44bnA250GMrV2&w=90&h=90&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.djmag.com%2Fimages%2Ftop100djs%2F2011header.jpg",
    "http://external.ak.fbcdn.net/safe_image.php?d=AQD44bnA250GMrV2&w=90&h=90&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.djmag.com%2Fimages%2Ftop100djs%2F2011header.jpg",
    "http://external.ak.fbcdn.net/safe_image.php?d=AQD44bnA250GMrV2&w=90&h=90&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.djmag.com%2Fimages%2Ftop100djs%2F2011header.jpg",
    "<null>",
    "<null>",
    "<null>",
    "<null>",
    "<null>"
    )' of class '__NSArrayM'
```

is this problem because of i will get null value in filter array?

Comment: What is filter image?  Does it contain and custom classes or classes that are not serializable?

Comment: filter image is my array.in that i array i have some images.i want to pass that image on another view array.

Comment: What data type are the images?

Comment: I am using NSMutableArray to store images.

Comment: What data type are the image data? NSMutableArray just contains other objects. Just because something can be placed in an NSArray does not mean that NSUserDefaults can save is.  See my answer for the kind of things that can be contained in an NSArray for NSUserDefaults.  As an example, if an UIImage is in the NSArray it can not be saved with NSUserDefaults.  Ypou may need to use NSArchiving to save your NSArray of images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NSUserDefaults can only contain a few data types: `BOOL, double, float, NSInteger, NSNumber, NSData, NSString, NSDate, NSArray, NSDictionary, NSURL`.  For other data types convert then to NSData or NSString.

Note that there are convince methods/functiions for many other data types to convert to and from NSStrings including `NSStringFromCGAffineTransform, NSStringFromCGPoint, NSStringFromCGRect, NSStringFromCGSize, NSStringFromRange, NSStringFromUIEdgeInsets, NSStringFromUIOffset` and their counterparts to recreate the data types from the `NSString` representations.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it will solve all of your problems, but don't forget to synchronize your userDefaults after you change them:

```
[userPrefs synchronize];
```

Comment: synchronize just updates the disk and is not needed within the app.

Answer (score 1):

```
 if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"FILTERIMAGE"]==nil)
   {
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:filterimage forKey:@"FILTERIMAGE"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
   }

then you can get where your want using entire application
FBImage = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"FILTERIMAGE"];
```

Comment: if you set proper object no problem at all.i think filterimage array is null

Comment: In filterimage array i got some null value & some image,whatever data come in filterimage data i posted in my question